# Setting Up Intel TBB with Nuwen

Tags: c++, mingw, tbb

I've recently become interested in learning more about parallel computing, concurrency, etc. My main language is C++, so obviously I decided to use that in my personal studies.

After some research (read: looking things up on Google), I decided that using Intel's TBB library would be the most ideal.

The one thing that's got me stuck so far, though, is setting it up to use on my computer. I have looked on the Internet for some sort of tutorial on setting TBB up with MinGW (in my case, specifically Nuwen) and haven't really found anything.

So, here's my question: how would I set up TBB to use with a Nuwen distro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TBB doesn't provides binaries for mingw in a Windows package. So you should build it from source code. You need compiler and GNU make;

Download source code(.zip) from https://github.com/01org/tbb/releases

Unpack somethere (not sure, but in common: beware of spaces in the dir path)

Open your console with compiler's environment, go to $archive_root/src and call `gmake tbb tbbmalloc compiler=gcc`. Also you could try to add `stdver=c++11` in the build command if your complier supports this mode.

You will find a library build in the $archive_root/build/windows_... directory

Comment: Where would I put the .dll file(s)? Do I just leave them there, or can I place them somewhere for MinGW to use them directly without any special parameters?

Comment: Also, do I do anything with the "include" folder's contents?

Comment: You can use `tbbvars.bat` file to setup TBB environment: it should be the better solution;
Also you could copy dll files to your build directory for build/run/deploy simplification

Comment: Will that work on Windows? I'm using Windows, and that didn't seem to do much of anything.

Comment: I guess you should run bat file inside your developer console;

Comment: Disregard the previous message. I have placed the contents of the "include" folder in MinGW's "include" directory, and that seems to work just fine. Thanks for the help!